# Компактный код вычисления среднего арифметического

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть код, который вычисляет среднее арифметическое из произвольного количества элементов, включая вычисления из массивов.

**логика: 20,30,[20,10] => (20+30+20+10)/4)**

Можно ли записать данный код компактнее ? Если можно то с помощью чего?

```js
function average() {
  let res = 0;
  let counts = 0;
  let resObj = 0;
  let isArray = 0;
  let devider = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (typeof(arguments[i]) == 'object') {
      isArray++
      for (j = 0; j < arguments[i].length; j++) {
        resObj += arguments[i][j];
        counts++
      }
    } else if (typeof(arguments[i]) == 'number') {

      res += arguments[i];
    } else return console.log('Including: ', typeof(arguments[i]));



  }
  res += resObj;
  devider = arguments.length + counts - isArray;
  res /= devider
  console.log('arrDevider:', counts, 'devider: ', devider, 'current result: ', res)
}
average(10, [4, 5], [20, 10])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function average( ...values ){
  let flat = values.flat();
  return flat.reduce(( accum, val )=> accum + val ) / flat.length;
}

console.log( average(10, [4, 5], [20, 10]) );
```